# Is there any way to ban the "sharepoint" tag?

Tags: support, tagging

The [sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint) tag is pure noise on this site, as all questions are about SharePoint.

Is there any way to ban this tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't ask this on meta.so as it is site specific.

I added `^sharepoint$` to the intrinsic tags for this site, so it won't be allowed and it will be removed from any migrated questions as well.

I also removed any existing [sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint) tags too.

Comment: What about tags that are preprended with `sharepoint-`?  Look at my question here: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/730/tag-adjustment-sharepoint-enterprise-enterprise

Answer (score 3):

Equally important: to get users to tag with **specific** SharePoint version.

Se my post here
[Is there a way to "force" or suggest the selection of tags?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/is-there-a-way-to-force-or-suggest-the-selection-of-tags)

Answer (score 1):

**I'm not a mod** so I don't know for certain if there's a way to "ban" a tag.

However, I'm pretty sure that if every question with the `sharepoint` tag is retagged appropriately and the `sharepoint` tag is manually removed from the database users who start typing in "sha..." when they're tagging their questions should no longer be prompted to use "sharepoint" as a tag.  Instead they should see `sharepoint-2010`, `sharepoint-2007`, etc.

Comment: Until the next person that creates it as a tag again :(