# Is there a way to "force" or suggest the selection of tags?

Tags: support, tagging

In SharePoint related questions 9 out of 10 times, it is imperative to have the post tagged with what version of the product we are talking about (eg. SharePoint-2007, SharePoint-2010, SharePoint-Foundation..). So is there a way to either enforce that the user select one from a group of tags, or less intrusive to get reminded to tag with one of those tags?

Coming to think about it... it really could be as simple as a text in the tagging area reminding users to tag SharePoint questions with version if relevant..

Comment: there must be, because meta forces you to select one of the 4 tags

Comment: I'm against forcing the selection.. Also, looks like one of the example suggestions is already `sharepoint-2010`.

Comment: @KitMenke: There is an algorithm that 'guesses' what you tag you are typing based on what's popular in the site. `sharepoint-2010` is the most popular right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange has the concept of required tags, but they're not generally used for this type of situation. No matter which tags you think should be required, there will be others who think the site should be sliced up another way; and they will always be the exception which fits none of the required tags. Deciding which tags should be included in a post is a combination of user preference and community convention.

A significant component of Stack Exchange is the [wiki-aspect](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/about) of improving contributions. If you feel a post needs an additional tag to provide clarity, request the information or edit the post to include that information.

Comment: Agreed, I can think of many a third party product that I might want to ask about here.  Or I may have a cross-product question (such as an upgrade scenario, etc), or an architectural SharePoint question that applies really to no particular version.